# Problems with left space with UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have this code below that can insert a left space in my `UITextField`:

```
@implementation UITextField (custom)
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 8,
                      bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 16);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
@end
```

No matter the class I insert this code all UITextField that exists in my project will take effect (Strange...). But the problem is that this piece of code is affecting also all the `UISearchBar` (Text and placeholders does not work the right way, break the layout).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can custom a textfield:

```
UITextField *textFiled = [[UITextField alloc]init];
textFiled.leftView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 0)];
textFiled.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: I have 144 TextField and only 2 SearchBar, I have two solutions: Edit all the frame of all my 144 Textfields (repeat 144x) or convert this SearchBars to an UITextField (and continue with my code).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to subclass of UITextField rather than Category of UITextField.

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@end

@implementation MyTextField 
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 8,
                      bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 16);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
@end
```